# GIS.SE Moderator Cards

Tags: discussion, design, community

We recently printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place..

If you're a gis.stackexchange moderator, would you be interested in having your own GIS Stack Exchange contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out during your local GIS meetups or conferences.

Below is a mockup:

(click on image to see full res version)

[image: gis.stackexchange moderator cards]

Of course Twitter ID/phone# are optional. It can be Skype, AIM, blog URL etc.

<sub>Note: the text rendering in the mockup is slightly blurry. But when printed it will be crisp.</sub>

Comment: What's the status of this idea?

Answer (score 6):

I regularly meet GIS people in my teaching and consulting work.  It would be easy to pass out cards or even leave a pile with some of the larger organizations.

Answer (score 4):

It's a good idea though I have not been to a GIS conference in 10+years - in the UK annual  GIS Event it went from strength to strength in 1990's but it started becoming less and less important and big mapping companies pulled out.

**As more and more GIS Events are now streamed and recorded over the internet** there is no need to travel/attend them. Have generated a small but trustworthy online community via my blog and solving mapping issues for hundreds of users. Mainly controlled by Twitter and now Google+1.

A virtual [vCard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard) or  Quick Response [QR Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) would also work

Answer (score 3):

OK, moderators have officially been mailed the form to obtain the cards. Stay tuned!

Comment: How do we order more after running out?